# converting string to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one question. I created a variable which contains the concatenated variable, 
e.g something like this:

```
$a=89111213
```

I want to obtain an array like this:

```
$b(
  1=>8,
  2=>9,
  3=>11,
  4=>12,
  5=>13
)
```

Comment: You just changed the entire meaning of your question, next time ask it as specifically as you can so people don't provide the wrong answers firsthand.

Comment: Really sorry bit new in this field

Comment: What logic is supposed to decide to split that as 8,9,11,12,13 rather than 8,9,1,1,1,2,1,3?  That the numbers increase?  That makes things rather a lot more complicated.

Comment: I wanted to get the integer number from that string e,g 8 9 10 11...

Comment: I'd say it is impossible without additional information. Event it is as @therefromhere says, you don't know if it is `89`, `111`, and `213`. Or maybe `891`, `1121` and now we have a `3` left over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

As @therefromhere suggests in his comment, instead of concatenating the numbers into one string,put them  in an array directly:

```
$a = array();

for(...) {
    $a[] = $somevariable;

}
```

---

Here is something that works in a way.

**Important:**
**Assumption:** Numbers are concatenated in increasing order and start with a number < 10 :)

```
$str = "89111213";
$numbers = array();
$last = 0;
$n = '';
for($i = 0, $l = strlen($str);$i<$l;$i++) {
    $n .= $str[$i];
    if($n > $last || ($i == $l - 1)) {
        $numbers[] = (int) $n;
        $last = $n;
        $n = '';
    }
}

print_r($numbers);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 13
)
```

Although this might work to some extend, it will fail in a lot of cases. Therefore:

How do you obtain `89111213` ? If you are generating it from the numbers 8,9,11, etc. you should generate something like `8,9,11,12,13`.

Comment: +1 for the approach, even if the original problem is wrong to start with.

Comment: I get that number somewhat like this $a.=$somevariable.And i go on concatinatind it

Comment: @siddesh.  If you're getting the numbers in, then add them to an array then! This will initialise an array and add an element to it: `$aArray = array(); $aArray[] = $somevariable;`

Comment: @therefromhere: I added your comment to my answer. If you want to provide it as your own answer, I will remove it and upvote yours :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/explode):

```
$b = explode(' ', $a);
```

Comment: Sorry let me redifine it correctly $a=811 and i want $b(1=>8,2=>11)

Answer (score 2):

This looks dangerous. Have you concatenated several numbers to one integer? Note that there's an upper limit on integer values so you may experience bugs with many elements.

Also note that your problem is not possible to solve correctly when the numbers have different lengths, because you cannot know which of these combinations (if any) is correct for `89111213`:

- 8, 9, 11, 12, 13
- 89, 111, 213
- 8, 9, 11, 1213
- 8, 91, 11213

You will need some sort of separator to make it stable and future proof.

Comment: oki so how can i store this number ie 89111213.So that i retrive it correctly like 8 9 11 12 13

Comment: @siddesh savant: You should not have `89111213` from the beginning. How do you get that number?

Comment: Use a separator! Just a simple space will suffice: `8 9 11 12 13` or a comma: `8,9,11,12,13` or whatever character you like the most/find most practical for your needs. Then just explode() it as in the previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
<? explode(" ", "a b c d e") ?>
```